# Iterate data to new rows with line break in SAS

Tags: sas

I have multiple lines of data in one field that I need to iterate out to their own rows. The issue is I do not have a traditional delimiter- they are only separated by line breaks. I have tried to use 
xp = prxchange('s/[\r+\n]/>/',-1,x) combined with scan, but the prxchange function is not working through the whole block of text. prxchange is only recognizing the first line break and removing the rest of the data. Any idea how to fix or different approaches?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "line break" if not some end of line marker character like carriage return or linefeed? How is that not a delimiter?

Comment: Yes, there is carriage return and linefeed which is why I am using \r \n but it only seems to pick up the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use SCAN() to parse the string. No need for the slower speed or complexity of regular expressions.

```
data want;
  set have;
  do row=1 to countw(x,'0D0A'x);
    line=scan(x,row,'0D0A'x);
    output;
  end;
run;
```